# Unable to put \geq or \leq when using polski along with newtxmath

Tags: fonts, math-mode

```
\documentclass[12pt]{mwrep}
\usepackage{polski}
\usepackage{newtxmath}
\begin{document}
Why can't I write $a \leq 3$ or
\[
a \geq 2
\]
\end{document}
```

Output:
[image]

When using combination of packeges shown in MWE above I'm unable to get some characters (`\geq` and `\leq`). When I comment `\usepackage{polski}` I get proper result.  Unfortunately I need this package. What can I do to fix this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use another order of the packages:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{mwrep}
\usepackage{newtxmath}
\usepackage{polski}
\begin{document}
Why can't I write $a \leq 3$ or
\[
a \geq 2
\]
\end{document}
```

or redefine the symbols:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{mwrep}
\usepackage{polski}
\usepackage{newtxmath}
\DeclareSymbolFont{Symbols}{OMS}{cmsy}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\leq}{\mathrel}{Symbols}{"14}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\geq}{\mathrel}{Symbols}{"15}
\begin{document}
Why can't I write $a \leq 3$ or
\[
a \geq 2
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: OK, that works. But it also causes my all equations to look differently. I liked previous appearance better. But if it is only way to get `\leq` and `\geq` I will have no choice...

Comment: see my edited answer

Comment: What other symbol need to be redeclared? Is there an easy way to check it (other that trying to type all symbols)?

Comment: you can have a look into the package `polski`

Comment: @Herbert This will use different symbols than those provided by `newtxmath`.

Comment: I know that ...

Answer (score 5):

The package `polski` redefines the `symbol` font to use `\OMS/plsy/m/n` instead of the usual `\OMS/cmsy/m/n`; the font has `\leq` and `\geq` in different places than the standard encoding (because it wants to use a slanted bar instead of the usual straight one); indeed it states

```
\DeclareMathSymbol{\xleq}{3}{symbols}{172}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\xgeq}{3}{symbols}{173}
\let\leq=\xleq
\let\geq=\xgeq
\let\le=\leq
\let\ge=\geq
```

which is the reason why you don't get the correct symbols if you load `newtxmath` after `polski`. On the other hand, if you invert the order, `polski` will define the math alphabets nullifying the loading of `newtxmath`. So the workaround should be

```
\usepackage{polski}
\usepackage{newtxmath}

\DeclareMathSymbol{\leq}{\mathrel}{symbols}{20}
   \let\le=\leq
\DeclareMathSymbol{\geq}{\mathrel}{symbols}{21}
   \let\ge=\geq
```

so that the two symbols are restored in the correct positions.

**Note.** It appears that the redefinition of those symbols should depend from the package option `plmath`, but actually it's always performed.